# Test proxy servers in c#

Tags: c#, proxy

I am trying to figure out how proxy server works & using Fiddler I am trying to see whether I can see the proxy server.

```
class Program{
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
setProxies();
}

private static void setProxies()
{
    string fullproxyaddress = "http://ec2-100-100-111-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com/OsProxy/getpage.aspx?p=";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.google.com");
    request.Accept = "text/html";
    request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
    request.Method = "GET";
     request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
     Uri newUri = new Uri(fullproxyaddress);
     WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
    myProxy.Address = newUri;
    request.Proxy = myProxy;
    try
         {
               string  html = new TimedWebClient { Timeout = 360000 }.DownloadString("www.google.com");
               html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
    }catch...
    }
   } 
    class TimedWebClient : WebClient
        {
            // Timeout in milliseconds, default = 600,000 msec
            public int Timeout { get; set; }
            public Encoding enc { get; set; }

            public TimedWebClient()
            {
                this.Timeout = 600000;
                this.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
            }

            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
            {
                var objWebRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
                objWebRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;
                objWebRequest.Proxy = this.Proxy;
                return objWebRequest;
            }
        }
```

In the fiddler I expect to see fullproxyaddr+www.google.com when I run this. Why do I only see www.google.com in the Host and "/" in URL.

thanks
R

Comment: Are you trying to get your code to work using the proxy, or are you trying to figure out how to get Fiddler to show the URL with the proxy? It seems like your code isn't using the proxy.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins, I am trying to get proxy to work and then see that in Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

With your code the way you have it, you are not using the `HttpWebRequest` object that you created with your proxy information attached. You don't need it if you are going to make the request using your `TimedWebClient` class, but you need to make sure you set the proxy information.

Here's a working example using the Fiddler proxy. Just swap out your proxy information and it should work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        setProxies();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void setProxies()
    {
        //Set our proxy information
        string fullproxyaddress = "http://localhost:8888";
        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(fullproxyaddress);
        myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("1", "1");

        try
        {
            //Initialize our object using the created proxy
            //Make the request
            string html = new TimedWebClient { Timeout = 360000, Proxy = myProxy }.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
            Console.Write(html);
        }
        catch { Console.Write("Error!"); }
    }
}
class TimedWebClient : WebClient
{
    // Timeout in milliseconds, default = 600,000 msec
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public Encoding enc { get; set; }

    public TimedWebClient()
    {
        this.Timeout = 600000;
        this.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var objWebRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        objWebRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        objWebRequest.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        return objWebRequest;
    }
}
```

As far as getting the full URL to show up in Fiddler, I'm not sure. Maybe messing around with Tools -> Fiddler Options -> Gateway could help you.

Comment: this works for google.com. When I try "http://www.dotnetperls.com/uri" why doesn't it work? I get 404 exception

Comment: Not sure. I just tested it, and it works for me. Did you put the full URL in there (http://www....)?

Comment: If I put http://www.dotnetpearls.com it works but if I put http://www.dotnetpearls.com/uri it gives 404 exception

Comment: Are you passing in "dotnetpearls.com/uri" or `http://www.dotnetpearls.com/uri`? It should be the latter.

Comment: It is the latter one.